# React and Node simple asymmetric encryption

Tags: node.js, reactjs, encryption

I want to establish a simple asymmetric encryption for exchanging data between my ReactJS frontend and my backend implemnted in NodeJS.
Furthermore, I've already successfully generated a public an private key (with Node's in-bulit crypto library) and I am aslo able to encrypt and decrypt data in my NodeJS envirnoment.

Now, I would like to like to send the generated public key to my ReactJS so that it can encrypt its payload before sending and the backend is able to decrypt the payload with the private key of the pair, afterwards. (Is this a correct approach??)

My problem is that I'm not sure which library I can use in my React frontend to properly use the backend's public key to encrypt my payload.

Thanks in advance for your help and recommendations.

Comment: if you just used an https (ssl) server, you would have such an encryption automatically. SSL certs are available for free with [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/)

Comment: There is a built-in, low level API for encryption and decryption on the front-end, though it is only available if you have HTTPS. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the encryption algorithm you're using you should search for a library that implements it, there shouldn't be an issue by using crypto lib in your backend and CryptoJS for instance in your frontend since both algorithms are implemented in the same way in each lib. you can check here a [list of crypto libraries for js](https://gist.github.com/jo/8619441)